# Odd NULL pointer behavior

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm attempting to implement a stack using a linked list. My stack constructor `createStack()` creates an empty (dummy) `Element` and returns a double pointer to that element (top of stack). My `push()` method checks if the stack has a dummy element; if it does it fills the dummy and returns, otherwise it allocates memory for a new element and does the necessary pointer updates.

The problem I have is that my `*stack->next` pointer apparently points to `NULL (0x0)` as it should, and then two lines later it doesn't equal `NULL (0x17)` but somehow passes the `NULL` test. Inside the call to push it equals `(0x17)` again but this time it fails the `NULL` test, as it should.

So my question is, what the heck is going on with this pointer? How/why did it change from `(0x0)` to `(0x17)`, and if it equals `(0x17)` how did it pass the `==NULL` test??

```
//main.c
int main () {

    struct Element **stack;

    stack = createStack();

    printf("stack: %p\n", stack );

    printf("*stack->next: %p\n", (*stack)->next );

    if ( (*stack)->next == NULL )
        printf("yes the pointer is null\n" );

    printf("*stack->next: %p\n", (*stack)->next );

    if ( (*stack)->next == NULL )
        printf("yes the pointer is null\n" );

    push ( stack, 1000 );

//stack.c

struct Element {
    int value;
    struct Element *next;
};

int push ( struct Element **stack, int el ) {

    if ( (*stack)->next == NULL) {
        // first element, fill dummy element and return
        printf("first value: %i !", el);
        (*stack)->value = el;
        return 1;
    }

    printf("the pointer is not null\n");

    struct Element *newElement = malloc( sizeof( struct Element ) );

    if ( !newElement )
        return -1;

    newElement->value = el;

    //add element to front of list
    newElement->next = *stack;

    //update pointer to new first element
    *stack = newElement;

    return 1;
}

struct Element** createStack() { 

    struct Element *dummy = malloc( sizeof( struct Element ) );

    if (dummy == NULL )
        printf("malloc failed...");

    dummy->value = 99;
    dummy->next = NULL;

    struct Element **stack;

    stack = &dummy;

    return stack;
}
```

The code above produces the following output:

```
stack: 0x7fff6c385ba8
*stack->next: 0x0
yes the pointer is null
*stack->next: 0x17
yes the pointer is null
the pointer is not null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget for a moment that you're working with pointers and pointers-to-pointers, and suppose your `createStack()` routine looked like this:

```
int *createInt() {
    int dummy = 1;
    return &dummy;
}
```

The function allocates (temporary) space on the stack for the local variable `dummy`, assigns it a value, and then returns a pointer to it.  This is exactly what your `createStack()` does, except that your `dummy` happens to be a more complicated data type.

The problem is that the memory allocated to `dummy` itself is released when the function returns and pops its local variables off the stack.  So the function returns a pointer to memory that has become available for re-use.  It then can (and does) change as data is pushed and popped from the stack during subsequent function calls.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dummy` within `createStack()` ceases to exist when that function returns - so the pointer that you return points at a variable which doesn't exist anymore.

This is why you see the odd behaviour - `printf()` is likely writing over the memory that formerly contained `dummy`, so when you try to examine that memory via your dangling pointer, you see it change unexpectedly.

You can fix the code by changing `createStack()` to return a `struct Element *` value:

```
struct Element *createStack(void)
{  
    struct Element *dummy = malloc( sizeof( struct Element ) );

    if (dummy == NULL )
        printf("malloc failed...");
    else {
        dummy->value = 99;
        dummy->next = NULL;
    }

    return dummy;
}
```

and changing `main()` to suit (`push()` can remain unchanged):

```
int main ()
{
    struct Element *stack;

    stack = createStack();

    printf("stack: %p\n", stack );

    printf("stack->next: %p\n", stack->next );

    if ( stack->next == NULL )
        printf("yes the pointer is null\n" );

    printf("stack->next: %p\n", stack->next );

    if ( stack->next == NULL )
        printf("yes the pointer is null\n" );

    push ( &stack, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `createStack` function you are returning the address of a local variable which leads to undefined behaviour:

```
struct Element** createStack() {

        struct Element *dummy = malloc( sizeof( struct Element ) );    
        ...
        struct Element **stack;    
        stack = &dummy;    
        return stack;
}
```

Instead you can just have a pointer to `struct Element` in main and return the pointer to the newly created node from the `createStack` function:

```
struct Element *stack = createStack();
```

And pass the address of the pointer `stack` to the `ush` function:

```
push ( &stack, 1000 );
```